# Ruby: How to create multiple hashes using their respective text file name in one block

Tags: ruby

I want to read in each line of multiple files (e.g. 3 files) to their own hash.

This is easy as three separate blocks:

```
cheap = Hash.new {|name, id| name[id] = ''}
File.open("cheap.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
  name, id = line.split(":")
  cheap[name] << id
end
cheap = cheap.sort_by{|k,v| v}

expensive = Hash.new {|name, id| name[id] = ''}
File.open("expensive.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
  name, id = line.split(":")
  expensive[name] << id
end
expensive = expensive.sort_by{|k,v| v}

auction = Hash.new {|name, id| name[id] = ''}
File.open("auction.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
  name, id = line.split(":")
  auction[name] << id
end
auction = auction.sort_by{|k,v| v}
```

But in the spirit of "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself) I am trying to write this in one block. I google'd and read up on some different methods, the best analogy I came close to was a "require" set up as such:

```
%w{rubygems daemons eventmachine}.each { |x| require x }
```

However if I try to apply this to my puzzle I run into the problem of trying to create a hash name out of the variable I've assigned it to:

```
%w{cheap.txt expensive.txt auction.txt}.each do |x|
    x = Hash.new {|name, id| name[id] = ''}
    File.open(x, 'r').each_line do |l|
        name, id = line.split(':')
        x.split(".")[name] << id
    end
end
```

This will obviously output the error that I'm trying to convert a string into a hash. How can I pull each line out of three separate files into their own hash object? For now I will use three separate blocks, but conceptually I'm very curious about this.

Comment: This is off-topic, should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of options. The easiest and closest to what you're trying to achieve is to store your hashes *in a hash*:

```
items = {}

%w{cheap.txt expensive.txt auction.txt}.each do |x|
    items[x] = Hash.new {|name, id| name[id] = ''}
    File.open(x, 'r').each_line do |l|
        name, id = line.split(':')
        items[x][name] << id
    end
end
```

Alternatively, wrap the actual loading in a function, which accepts a filename:

```
def load_file(filename)
  data = Hash.new {|name, id| name[id] = ''}
  File.open("expensive.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
    name, id = line.split(":")
    data[name] << id
  end
  data.sort_by{|k,v| v}
end

cheap = load_file('cheap.txt')
expensive = load_file('expensive.txt')
auction = load_file('auction.txt')
```

Comment: I assume it's bad form to create variables that will only delete themselves out of the block scope anyhow.

However, for the last three lines (again just out of curiousity) is it possible to make that a one liner?

I seem obsessed with minimizing the code, but really I am just curious because this is a new language for me and I'm wondering what all can be done still -- Thank you for the answer, the second is what I ended up doing.

The weirdest thing I tried to do what create a hash of variable names and their respective text file and then try to feed that into a function. That did not work xP

Comment: Nvm I got it! One line of awesomeness. cheap, expensive, auction = load(cheap.txt), load(exp.txt), load(auc.txt)